# Exclude location from nginx if directive

Tags: nginx, mod-rewrite

Currently I use this for redirecting everybody to the SSL page:

```
if ($scheme != "https") {
    rewrite ^ https://$server_name$request_uri? permanent;
}
```

does someone know how to exclude a specific location?

For example if I want to exclude news.jpg or news.php

Thanks for your help!

Comment: It's better to hve two separate server blocks for http and https.

Comment: Currently not possible because of the server admininistration software I use. But thanks for the hint!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick. We include the https redirect in a location block, and then we define additional empty location blocks for the locations we do not want to redirect. nginx will match the more specific location blocks first, so it won't match the redirect block.

`return 301` is a bit faster method for simple redirects like here.

```
location / {
    if ($scheme != "https") {
        return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
    }
}

location /news.jpg {
}
```